# check VAT number webservice call

Tags: java, web-services

I tried to write a program, that simply checks the validity of a VAT number. I would like to use the webservice here: https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService.wsdl
I followed this tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/java-soap-web-service) and got maven to generate some classes in my project with the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ffleuchten.vatchecker</groupId>
<artifactId>VatChecker</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <packageName>com.ffleuchten.vatchecker.generated</packageName>
                <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Generated classes are as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca 2.2K Nov 15 15:15 CheckVat.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca 6.8K Nov 15 15:15 CheckVatApprox.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca  13K Nov 15 15:15 CheckVatApproxResponse.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca 6.4K Nov 15 15:15 CheckVatPortType.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca 5.2K Nov 15 15:15 CheckVatResponse.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca 3.1K Nov 15 15:15 CheckVatService.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca 4.9K Nov 15 15:15 ObjectFactory.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 manoca manoca  221 Nov 15 15:16 package-info.java
```

It was a bit weird after generating those classes, as the import statements generated were wrong. It generated invalid imports like:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
```

which I let my eclipse change to

```
import jakarta.xml.ws.Service;
```

imports.

After that everything compiled fine and I made this class to try it out:

```
package com.ffleuchten.vatchecker;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.ffleuchten.vatchecker.generated.CheckVatPortType;
import com.ffleuchten.vatchecker.generated.CheckVatService;

import jakarta.xml.ws.Holder;

public class TestVAT {

    private String countryCode;
    private String vatNumber;

    public TestVAT(String countryCode, String vatNumber) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.vatNumber = vatNumber;
    }

    private void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("checking VAT number "
                    .concat(this.vatNumber)
                    .concat(" with country code ")
                    .concat(this.countryCode)
                    .concat("..."));
            
            CheckVatService service = new CheckVatService();
            CheckVatPortType port = service.getCheckVatPort();
            
            Holder<String> countryCodeHolder = new Holder<String>(this.countryCode); 
            Holder<String> vatNumberHolder = new Holder<String>(this.vatNumber);  
            Holder<XMLGregorianCalendar> requestDateHolder = new Holder<XMLGregorianCalendar>(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(LocalDate.now().toString()));
            Holder<Boolean> validHolder = new Holder<Boolean>(false); 
            Holder<String> nameHolder = new Holder<String>("?"); 
            Holder<String> adressHolder = new Holder<String>("?");
            
            port.checkVat(countryCodeHolder, vatNumberHolder, requestDateHolder, validHolder, nameHolder, adressHolder);
            
            System.out.println("VAT number "
                    .concat(vatNumberHolder.value)
                    .concat(" with country code ")
                    .concat(countryCodeHolder.value)
                    .concat(" is ")
                    .concat(validHolder.value.booleanValue() ? "valid" : "invalid")
                    .concat(" and belongs to ")
                    .concat(nameHolder.value)
                    .concat(" who lives at ")
                    .concat(adressHolder.value)
                    .concat("!"));
            
            System.out.println("VAT number checked! exiting now...");
            System.exit(0);
            
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("no country code passed as parameter!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if(args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("no VAT number passed as parameter!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String countryCode = args[0];
        String vatNumber = args[1];
        new TestVAT(countryCode, vatNumber).run();
    }

}
```

This still compiles and even runs, but no matter what VAT number and/or countrycode I use I always get the following output:

```
checking VAT number DE814416365 with country code DE...
VAT number DE814416365 with country code DE is invalid and belongs to --- who lives at ---!
VAT number checked! exiting now...
```

So am I doing something wrong here, or does the webservice really always responds with 'VAT number is invalid'(which it seems to be the case as it overwrites name and adressvalues with '---')?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use correct VAT numbers (the "DE" part is not part of the VAT number) it works! I don't know why the webservice does not respond with an error instead of giving a "not valid" information, but hey, it works :)

Comment: invalid IS the error. You're sending an invalid VAT number.

Comment: In my opinion there should be a difference between an invalid formatted uid and an invalid uid. But what do I know.